# Monterey - Disable fading animation when switching between fullscreen windows

Tags: desktop, fullscreen

I am happy to see that, in **Monterey**, the "swiping animation" that happened when switching between fullscreen windows has disappeared. But now there is instead a fading animation, that sometimes even displays a glimpse of the wallpaper for even a slight second.

Is there a way to disable *all* animations, so that the change between windows is instantaneous, the same way that it is between non-fullscreen windows?